# Understanding the Notory on the Corda Enterprise

Tags: corda

1- Is there the possibility of creating more than 1 Notary for  "Double-spending" validation in Corda Enterprise? The reason why I am asking this is to know if there is and alternative contingency in case the Notary server is offline.

2 - Would it be possible to use Oracle database at the Notary?

3 - Does the Notary depend on the Network-Map? If so, could you explain to me why?

4 - Is the Network-Map implemented in Corda Enterprise?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1- Is there the possibility of creating more than 1 Notary for
>   "Double-spending" validation in Corda Enterprise? The reason why I am
>   asking this is to know if there is and alternative contingency in case
>   the Notary server is offline.

Yes. It is possible to create more than one Notary. However one transaction can be notarized by single notary only. Contigency plan when Notary server is offline -

1. Notary can be deployed as a cluster with BFT or Raft consensus
2. Framework has flow checkpointing mechanism. So if notary is down, flow will save itself and wait till the notary comes back online. The transaction processing is synchronous in Corda. It is not successful untill it gets committed on all the nodes and notary.

> 2 - Would it be possible to use Oracle database at the Notary?

Yes. Oracle database can be configured for Notary for Corda v3.1+ version only.

> 3 - Does the Notary depend on the Network-Map? If so, could you explain to me why?

Every node in Corda depends on network map. The network map is mechanism by which a Corda node discovers other nodes in the network. So notary also caches the network map locally. Periodically, the nodes receive this network map from Network Map Server present in the network.

> 4 - Is the Network-Map implemented in Corda Enterprise?

I think you mean Network Map server. Currently R3 has plans to launch production grade CordaNet. This will have implementation of network map server. However for private networks, the network operator is supposed to implement the Network Map Server.

Comment: Please, help me for configuration a "Setting up the Notary Service" in Oracle:
[Setting up the Notary Service] https://docs.corda.r3.com/running-a-notary-cluster/installing-the-notary-service.html

Comment: notary {
  mysql {
      connectionRetries={{ number of Percona nodes }}
      dataSource {
          autoCommit="false"
          jdbcUrl="jdbc:mysql://{{ your cluster IPs }}/{{ DB name, e.g. corda }}?rewriteBatchedStatements=true&useSSL=false&failOverReadOnly=false"
          username={{ DB username }}
          password={{ DB password }}
      }
  }
  validating=false
  serviceLegalName="O=HA Notary, C=GB, L=London"
}